# ssd caching in loop device on btrfs

Tags: linux, cache, ssd, btrfs

I have an ssd and 2TB hard disk. The ssd is used for the root filesystem which uses only around 20G of the 120G available.
Is there a way to use an image/loop on the root filesystem (btrfs) as a cache for the 2TB drive?

Comment: Yes. I do it w/ [`bcache`.](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/)

Comment: Since you are on btrfs, you should probably disable COW for the loop file if you do this. But it'd be much simpler to resize the SSD partition and use a raw partition for caching; any reason why you don't want this instead?

Comment: yes, nocow is a must. The complete harddrive is encrypted and i dont like unencrypted partitions. I would be just more flexible.

Comment: @Jodka Ah, I see. I have a similar setup with a LUKS volume that contains the root btrfs filesystem and a bcache cache device, but I've set up LVM inside the LUKS volume, which allows this partitioning to be done easily; I'm  guessing that you don't have LVM inside LUKS. If you have partitioning outside the LUKS volume, you can shrink both the btrfs filesystem and LUKS volume and create a new partition containing a bcache cache device in a new LUKS volume. I haven't tried bcache using a nocow loop file, so I'm not sure how much performance would be lost compared to a raw encrypted device.